pyspark How to read a folder with binary files continuously - on new files
I created a pyspark pipeline that begins on reading binary files:
unzipped: DataFrame = spark.read.format("binaryFile")\
            .option("pathGlobFilter", "*.pcap.tgz")\
            .option("compression", "gzip")\
            .load(folder)

After "unzipping" i untar them and extract ip-udp packages with proprietary package format.
Is there a pyspark way to execute the pipeline on new files or do i need some kind of wrapper to "observe" the folder? I would like to avoid polling but have something filesystem event based.
I would like to move processed files into a done folder.
I know there is "stream processing" but i am not sure if this is applicable here. At least there a re some use cases where i need data from previous files accessible.

If you’re using Databricks this thread might be helpful https://community.databricks.com/t5/data-engineering/read-just-the-new-file/td-p/14624

no i am not using databricks
